Raven's Matrix: 3-by-3 grids colored blue and green
This matrix is part of the app "IQ Test: Raven Matrices", level 27. I can't identify the pattern. Can you explain how to solve it?


Op was it the correct answer for the test?

I don't know the correct answer but your answer made sense as a way to solve this matrix.

I see, I had a theory for one too but this answer seemed more ‘Like what the puzzle creator intended’ than the other.

There are several Reddit communities dedicated to solving questions like these you should post it there to get second opinions. PSE doesn’t have a big audience anymore for iq puzzles it seems.

For example: https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1

I think the answer is:

 Option 2 (from the left)

Reason

 The rule is that every row has 3 blue regions enclosed and only option two allows for this in the final row:
 

